# How should I go about combining two iPhone apps with identical class names?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two apps with very similar code bases, but full of different data, labels, images, etc.

I'd like to make a new app with two buttons on launch, one for each app.

I can't just combine them, because the apps share a lot of same class names.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The find and replace function in Xcode to rename them :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446498/how-to-combine-two-cocos2d-projects-to-one-app

Comment: Refactor tool which you could use to totally rename, or add an identifier to the beggining of one set of classes

Comment: thanks for the comments... is there a way to refactor every file at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to refactor every file at once?

No, there's no tool in Xcode to rename all the identifiers in an app at the same time. However, if you use the Rename tool, you can change all uses of a given identifier at once, which is a huge time saver. You could easily rename several dozen classes in an hour or less.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Refactor" functionality of Xcode.

First create your one project. Make everything you want. Then, just refactor the project and give second project name.

So that, you will have 2 copy of the project with different name and you can achieve your goal.

Happy Coding.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename all classes !

As a project don't contain same name class.

Simple add some extension for differentiate you class,
like

LoginViewController_firstapp.h

and

LoginViewController_secondapp.h e.t.c.

using Refactor tool! Its works like a charm!

Enjoy coding

[image: Refactor view]