# how to integrate two project in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, gstreamer

I have two xcode projects one is a Gstreamer project( using Gstreamer single view  templet) and other is a single view ios application. Now I want to integrate them into a single project. How can I do that.

Few things that I have tried:
1. I created a new project and copied the .xcodeproj files of both projects but I did not know what to do with the main.m file and storyboard file(I have one storyboards in gstreamer project and one in the other).
2.I tried copying the the UI project into Gstreamer project.
3.Tried copying gstreamer into UI project.

Should I create a Gstreamer project and the UI project into it or vice-versa or should I create a normal project and add both the projects into it.
I am really confused.

Please suggest the right way of doing this.

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences) helps you

Comment: simple drag .xcodeproj files to xcode navigator area -> your folder.

Comment: @Reming Hsu  can u please elaborate...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes a lot of sense when you are trying to integrate two project into one. There are a couple steps required for doing this.you can refer  following link to do this. [Xcode 4.2 how include one project into another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one)

Comment: @nikhil thanks for accepting plz up vote for my ans.

Answer (score 0):

simple drag .xcodeproj files to xcode navigator area -> your folder.
something like this.

[image]

Comment: how to access file of Project B in ProjectA in current