# How to include one Xcode project into another?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-workspace

I have two (A and B) Xcode projects with two different identifiers. Now I want to open Project B on click of button in Project A.I dont want to open another app from one app.I just want to combine my two projects. It has to be only one project which includes both.In workspace I am able to add both projects. but how to interlink them?
Any leads about making static library of one of the projects?
I am confused which is the better way to do this.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one . Much similar with latest xcode as well.

Comment: No its not because I have existing xcode project and not the static library project. Project B has as many as 500 .h, .m and Xib's and more than 10 third party libabries. now I wan to add this whole project into another one which may or may not have same third party libraries added. this is driving me nuts.

Comment: @ArpitJain any leads?

Comment: how did you do it then? any luck?