# Putting Pod installed project inside another project of Xcode.

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xcode9

I have to put projB inside ProjA. Both projects has installed pods. Also, projB is a Objective C project and ProjA is a Swift project. Could anyone please let me know how to do it. 
I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one) soultion. But It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know any project should only have one pod file, so u can copy the content of projectB's podFile ( not the whole content but the pods' names to project A's pod file , and then run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check pod versions. after that you can copy Project A podfile to B Project. You cant Use Both project pod files into one project as i think.