# Xcode 4.2: How to import .h file from subproject

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode subprojects. In my iPhone app project `MyProject`, I am trying to refactor some common code to a static library project called `MyLibrary`. After I create `MyLibrary` and move the code, `MyProject` is no-longer compiling. The error is that the `MyProject` cannot see the .h files in `MyLibrary`.

The error `MyLibraryConfig.h: No such file or directory` is coming in the line:

```
#import "MyLibraryConfig.h"
```

- How to import the `MyLibrary` .h files in `MyProject` ?
- What is the best practice here? Assuming I have multiple such libraries, it is tedious to add these to header search paths to the parent project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe your header file is also in a subdirectory.

Imagine the following directory setup:

```
- Desktop
    - MyProject
        - MyProject.xcodeproj
        - main.m

        - MyLibrary
            - MyLibrary.xcodeproj
            - MyHeaderFile.h      <-- wanted header file
```

If **main.m** has these contents:

```
#include "MyHeaderFile.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (gcc) will think that **MyHeaderFile.h** is located in the same directory as **main.m**, from which it is included. To tell the compiler you mean the header file in a subfolder, you have can do two things.

- You can add a directory to the gcc compiler that says: "hey, also look in that folder". You can do this by using the `-iquote myFolder` flag.
- You can include the directory in the include-statement: `#include "MyLibrary/MyHeaderFile.h"`

There could of course be another problem, but this seams like the most straightforward one.

Comment: For the first bullet, that hey, also look in that folder setting is HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in the Build Settings.

Comment: @lef2, rooftop: Thanks for the answer. However, any easier way?  Assuming I have multiple such libraries, it is tedious to add these to header search paths to the parent project.

Comment: Ok, Header search paths has a recursive flag. This looks good. via http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/ .

Comment: What if I wanted to do the opposite? If I had a MyView.m file in MyLibrary and I wanted to import a file called Constants.h that was in the MyProject directory?

Comment: `#include "../MyHeaderFile.h"` should do the trick. Or `-iquote ..`. `../` is the UNIX alias to the parent directory. Of course you'll have to setup the flag for your library Xcode project instead of your other one.

Answer (score 28):

In build settings --> Header Search Path --> Add below entry

$(SRCROOT) and mark it as recursive.

[image]

Comment: your little screen shot saved me a WHOLE LOT of hair pulling!

Comment: Definitely the best solution!