# How to access subprojects header file in main project

Tags: iphone

I have one main project and another project which is added as a subprojects. I want to access header file which is defined in subproject into the main projects but unfortunate it is saying file not find error.

Please have look on the attach image. what should I modify to access header files of subprojects?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.2: How to import .h file from subproject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501799/xcode-4-2-how-to-import-h-file-from-subproject)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to add the path of the sub project to the `search path for headers` in the main project, for reading how to do it check this [Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)

Comment: I set HEADER_SEARCH_PATH with "${SRCROOT}" but it still saying header file not fine.

Comment: it should be the real path of your sub project, such as home/projects/yourproject/

Comment: yes it is compiling fine. But when I am trying to load it in navigation I am getting an linker error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SubViewContoller",".
And my statement of code is "      subView = [[SubViewContoller alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubViewContoller" bundle:nil];".

Comment: allocation is not happening for subproject header files.