# Accessing function in xcode subproject

Tags: ios

I have an xcode project and it has a subproject.

```
projectA.xcodeproj
    projectB.xcodeproj
    scripts
    sdks
    projectA
    resources
```

Currently I am in a file in projectA but need to access a function in projectB. This function is also dependent on custom SDKs within Project B.  How might I go about this? So far I have tried to expand the header file search to Users/me/DocumentsProjectA/ProjectB with no success.

Comment: You should look into workspaces for this

Comment: I am referring to nested projects and not workspaces.

Comment: There's already answers for this online. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501799/xcode-4-2-how-to-import-h-file-from-subproject) seems similar to what you're talking about

Comment: Okay. So I realized I was changing the user header search paths and not just the header search paths. Now I am able to access the header files.