# Is it possible to access a class from a different project in the same workspace?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I can create a workspace and add two different Xcode project in that workspace. Inside that workspace, is there a way to access from one project's class to other project's class?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501799/xcode-4-2-how-to-import-h-file-from-subproject ?

Comment: I would recommend creating a framework with the code that's meant to be shared.

Comment: Actually I have no idea for creating framework.

Comment: Larme, I have checked the link and Search Header File looks like a good solution but did not work though.

Comment: see that rectangle named "Target Membership" on the right side? Thats your friend. All created projects on one workspace (aka Targets) appear there and you select file by file what is part where and even multiple selections possible

Comment: Ok, but, when I select iOSPlugin file I see Unity-Project related targets and for my RCController files I only see Demo as a Target.