# Error in including header path between projects in same workspace

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have workspace with 5 projects, and i created a new view controller in one project and when i tried to include that controller as a header in another project, it throws me error 'file not found'
I tried the steps given in 
[two projects in xcode4 workspaces (#import failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271026/two-projects-in-xcode4-workspaces-import-failure)
 , but still it does not work. Any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build settings for the naughty project that throws the error, add the header file's path to "User Search paths"

Comment: Thanks Owen, that works. The other solution i found is create a project header file that imports all the controllers header file in thh project, then have that project header file included in the .pch file of the other project where you are trying to use it.